# Поиск элементов в массиве(Pascal)

Tags: pascal

Всем привет!
есть задание
Найти в массиве элементы, равные числу, заданному пользователем. Подсчитать их количество и вывести номер первого найденного элемента. Массив задается при помощи ввода с клавиатуры.

```
const count=10;
var a,b,
i: integer;

m: array [1..count] of integer;
begin 
writeln ('Ввод исходного массива: ');
for i:=1 to count do 
begin
write('Значение#', i, ':');
readln(m[i]);
end;
a:=0; b:=0
write('Введите число для поиска > ');
readln(n);
for i:=1 to count do {Поиск элемента, равного n}
if m[i]=n then 
begin
if b=0 then a:=i;{Запоним номер первого эелемнта, равного n}
b:=b+1;{Увеличим число найденных элементов на 1}
end;
if b=0 then writeln('Нет таких элементов в массиве?'}
else 
begin
writeln('Кол-во элементов массива, имеющих значение',n,'=',b:3);
writeln('Первый элемент имеет номер',a:3);
      
end
end.
```

Но все равно почему-то выдает ошибку, что надо исправить?

Comment: "почему-то выдает ошибку" - ??

Comment: Ошибка то в чем заключается? Я не специалист в pascal (ниразу не притрагивался к нему), но где у вас инициализация `n`?

Answer (score 1):

Ниже пример рабочего кода. Если хотите узнать в чем были ошибки, сравните коды.

```
const count=10;
var 
  a,b,i,n: integer;
  m: array [1..count] of integer;
begin 
  writeln ('Ввод исходного массива: ');
  for i:=1 to count do 
  begin
    writeln('Значение# ', i, ': ');
    readln(m[i]);
  end;
  a:=0; b:=0;
  writeln('Введите число для поиска > ');
  readln(n);
  for i:=1 to count do {Поиск элемента, равного n}
    if m[i]=n then 
    begin
      if b=0 then a:=i;{Запоним номер первого эелемнта, равного n}
      b:=b+1;{Увеличим число найденных элементов на 1}
    end;
 
  if b=0 then 
     writeln('Нет таких элементов в массиве')
  else 
  begin
    writeln('Кол-во элементов массива, имеющих значение',n,'=',b:3);
    writeln('Первый элемент имеет номер',a:3);
  end
end.
```

Весь прикол в том, что я человек, который ниразу не кодил на паскале, просто открыл онлайн компилятор, который сказал где ошибки). Добавил пару табуляций для понимая и нашел еще одну ошибку.

Comment: У Вас потеряна логика else в последнем блоке [https://ideone.com/pl2yh5](https://ideone.com/pl2yh5)

Comment: @MBo ой,  а я то думал зачем этот else.